# HTML5 Canvas drawImage() inside object literal

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, object-literal

I'm trying to make a snake game with HTML5 using the object literal pattern, but I can't seem to draw an image on the canvas. I've researched a lot and found for instance that I can't set the image `src` while the object is being created (so I've put that in a function). The image seems to be available as it shows up in the console and can be appended to the body. What am I missing please?

```js
(function ($) {
  $.fn.preload = function() { // http://stackoverflow.com/a/476681
    this.each(function(){
        $('<img/>')[0].src = this;
    });
  }
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(['./images/grass-500x500.png']).preload(); // I've tried with and without this function (defined elsewhere)

  // Object literal pattern
  var game = {
    // Background image
    background: new Image(),
    setBGSource: function() {
      this.background.src = 'images/grass-500x500.png';
    },

    // Canvas details
    canvas: $("#canvas")[0],
    ctx: canvas.getContext("2d"),
    WIDTH: $("#canvas").width(),
    HEIGHT: $("#canvas").height(),

    // Game details
    CELL_WIDTH: 10,
    direction: null,
    food: null,
    score: null,
    snakeArray: [],

    init: function() {
      this.direction = "right";
      this.createSnake();
      this.setBGSource();
      this.draw();
    },

    createSnake: function() {
      var length = 5; // Initial length of snake
      for (var i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        this.snakeArray.push({
          x: i,
          y: 1 // y : 0 - initial position of snake in cell units
        });
      }
    },

    // Create food item
    createFood: function() {
      this.food = {
        x: Math.round(Math.random() * (WIDTH - CELL_WIDTH) / CELL_WIDTH),
        y: Math.round(Math.random() * (HEIGHT - CELL_WIDTH) / CELL_WIDTH)
      } // Position of food with x and and y between 0 and e.g 44
    },

    // Drawing function
    draw: function() {
      // Repaint the background on each frame
      console.log(this.background); // displays <img src="images/grass-500x500.png">
      this.ctx.drawImage(this.background, 0, 0); // WHY DOESN'T THIS WORK PLEASE?
      $('body').append(this.background); // appends image, no problem
    }

  };

  game.init();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that the image is being preloaded asynchronously while at the same time you call `game.init()` and thus `game.draw()`, which expects the image being loaded already.

Thus, unless the image is in your browser's cache, the asynchronous preloading might not have finished at the time of `game.draw()`.

You need to wait until preloading has finished before calling `game.init()`. JavaScript offers some good tools in dealing with asynchronous execution, e.g. callbacks, promises etc.

Have a look here: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/24102/resource-loader-for-an-html5-and-javascript-game

Comment: I'm using the Object Literal Pattern because I want to start writing better structured code. It looks like this might be causing more problems than it solves in this instance. Is there a way to put all that loader from the link into the object literal? Or does it necessarily need to remain outside?